# Is there a way to print all variables defined/visible within a makefile?

Tags: makefile

let's assume the following Makefile:

```
FOO=1
BAR?=test
BLAH:=$(BAR)

target:
   @echo "helloworld"
```

Is there a way it can show me variables like this (\n or \s) ?

```
FOO
BAR
BLAH
```

bonus question:
if it is possible, is there a way to also get external variables?
make target BLABLAH=toto or export BLABLAH=toto; make target

```
FOO
BAR
BLAH
BLABLAH
```

Comment: You could run a recipe that runs nothing but `env`, and if you wanted only the variable names, pipe that to `cut -d= -f1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say so specifically but because of the syntax I'll assume you're using GNU make.  In that case you can use the [`.VARIABLES` special variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-_002eVARIABLES-_0028list-of-variables_0029):

```
$(info Variables: $(.VARIABLES))
```

Note, that `make target BLABLBAH=toto` does *not* create an "external variable" (that term is not well-defined so I'm just guessing that by this you mean variables that are inherited from the environment and not set in the makefile).  Setting a variable on the command line creates a real make variable and it will be shown in the list above.

Variables obtained from the environment are imported into make as makefile variables and will also appear in the above list.